# Why is no one working in my lumberyard?

Tags: cult-of-the-lamb

I’m playing *Cult of the Lamb* on the Nintendo Switch, and my little cult is essentially stagnating because I’ve completely run out of lumber.

I built a Lumberyard, but I can’t seem to get any of my followers to work in it. I tried talking to them and assigning them the job “chop trees”, which doesn’t help.

The Stone Mine that I also built was always busy and produced stone until it broke after a while. I don’t remember having to tell anyone to work in it.

How can I make use of my Lumberyard?

Comment: I now believe it was a bug. Once I was able to scrounge up enough wood, I tore down the lumberyard and built a new one. It was immediately automatically occupied by a worker and started to produce wood.

Comment: The game is quite buggy, and workers not working on various builds (farms, refinery, lumberyard / stone mines) is something that I'm still seeing frequently on 1.0.12. At this moment quitting the game and reloading sometimes helps.